# JQuery dialog stops opening after switching (jquery) tab

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a website using jquery tabs. On one tab, there is a button opening a dialog form. The dialog form content is loaded dynamically using `.load(url)`.

The dialog form doesn't open anymore after doing the following steps:

1. Open the tab with the open dialog -button
2. Navigate to another tab
3. Navigate back to the step 1 tab

During step 1 the button works just fine, but after navigating somewhere else and back it suddenly stops working. Some part of javascript code must be interfering with something else but I have no idea what.

**Index.php:**

```
<script>
    $(function()
    {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="main.php">Main</a></li>
        <li><a href="somepage.php">Page2</a></li>
        <!-- etc. -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Main.php:**

```
<script src="dialogs.js"></script>
<button id="btnOpenDialog">Open dialog form</button>

<div id="dialog-form"></div>
```

**Dialogs.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#dialog-form").dialog();
    $("#dialog-form").load("dialogcontent.php");
    $("#dialog-form-accordion").accordion();
    $("#btnOpenDialog").click(function()
    {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    });
    $("#btnCloseDialog").click(function()
    {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("close");
    });
});
```

**Dialogcontent.php** includes the `dialog-form-accordion` and `btnCloseDialog`.

**UPDATE**:

I am getting `SCRIPT5022: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'` error on the console when clicking the button.

**UPDATE 2:**

Now after setting `$("#dialog-form").dialog({});` inside `$("#btnOpenDialog").button().click(function(){});` it "kind of" works.

After switching tab back and forth, first button click still returns the above error but if you click it again (after like two seconds or so) it suddenly works?!

What on earth is jquery doing? It can't take so long to initialize the dialog?

Comment: What do you mean it stops working? Doesn't open?

Comment: Any errors in the console? Can you reproduce this is a jsFiddle?

Comment: @Wilmer, yes, stops opening.

Comment: Why do you have the href attribute for that <a> i mean as far as I know it is only used to point which div to show when clicking the element but you have another page called main.php it won't be better using an iframe to that page or merge de script and in the page with the tabs load the contents of dialogcontent.php.
It will work as expected all in one page http://jsfiddle.net/xd96U/

Comment: @j08691, no errors in the console. I am not sure whether I can reproduce it in jsFiddle as I have multiple pages.

Comment: @EduardoQuintana Having everything in a single page (index.php) is something I am trying to avoid here as the page would eventually get too huge to maintain. Having all pages and content in different files and loaded via ajax when switching tab, clicking button etc. is so much cleaner option.

Comment: I know that i will become a huge horrible page to maintain. When you open you tab the dialog is immediately shown then you close it and change from tab , select again the tab of main.php and the dialog doesn't work anymore?

Comment: @EduardoQuintana The dialog is closed by default and only opens after clicking the `btnOpenDialog`. The dialog's content is loaded within the `$(document).ready(){};` and the content includes a 'Save' and 'Close' buttons. 'Close' button has the ID `btnCloseDialog` which closes the dialog. After you switch back and forth between the tabs the `btnOpenDialog` doesn't open the dialog anymore.

Comment: Hmm,, weird are you doing an ajax request each time you click on a tab or the contents in each one are loaded on index.php?

Comment: @EduardoQuintana Each time you click on a tab.

Comment: Quite interesting, I have no idea what I did but now I am starting to get `SCRIPT5022: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'` on console. Tab switching breaks the `$("#dialog-form").dialog({});` initialization in `dialogs.js`?